# Java IO / NIO : Can Server listen on more than one port?

Tags: java, tcp, io

I am working on Java IO/NIO. I have implemented many server/client applications for both TCP and UDP (Java IO) and recently started working on NIO.

I want to write a Server(TCP or UDP) which performs more than one task while listening to **more than one port**. I have always implemented server listening to a single port at a time and my question may be against best practices. But is there any way that a server can accept clients on multiple ports? Like more than one server inside a single server?

I am not looking for the code, just the concepts/design of the program if it is possible or not.

Server:

```
public class ServerAll implements Runnable {

private Socket connection;

ServerAll(Socket s) {
    this.connection = s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port1 = 7777;
    int port2 = 8888;
    int port3 = 9999;
    int count = 0;
    try{
        ServerSocket server1 = new ServerSocket(port1);
        ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket(port2);
        ServerSocket server3 = new ServerSocket(port3);

        System.out.println("Server Initialized");
        while (true) {
        Socket con1 = server1.accept();
        Runnable runnable1 = new ServerAll(con1);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable1);
        thread1.start();

        Socket con2 = server2.accept();
        Runnable runnable2 = new ServerAll(con2);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
        thread2.start();

        Socket con3 = server3.accept();
        Runnable runnable3 = new ServerAll(con3);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnable3);
        thread3.start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

public void run() {
    try {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        String clientMsg = in.readUTF();
        String replyMsg = null;

        if(clientMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            String msg = "Server Reply on 1";
            replyMsg=msg;
        }

        if(clientMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            String msg = "Server Reply on 2";
            replyMsg=msg;
        }

        if(clientMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            String msg = "Server Reply on 3";
            replyMsg=msg;
        }

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(replyMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class ClientTcpE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 7777;
    System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");
    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        Socket client = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("Just connected to "+ client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        out.writeUTF("1");
        System.out.println("Just sent msg to server");

        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        String serverMsg = in.readUTF();

        System.out.println("server says : "+serverMsg);
        client.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What NIO? What UDP? There is nothing but TCP and java.net here.

Comment: Code was added later, basically the question wasn't restricted to TCP (which is used in the code provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea sure.  The simple way is to have a number of threads each of which creates a [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html), binds to a port, and then calls `accept` on it.

Comment: Just did what you mentioned, I had done it earlier also. But when I try to run the same client on the same port again, it doesn't work. The program runs and no reply from server. Is it due to the blocking statements of Java IO?

Comment: @kami101 - Your code (above) does NOT do what I said.  You need to do the accept call in the child threads ... not in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are only accepting one port at a time, i.e. the accept()s are all in the same thread. You are only processing one message per client.  The way you have written the code, the client must contact the three ports in order, repeating.

If you want to accept connection on different ports concurrently you will have to use a Thread each for this blocking operation (or use non blocking NIO)